# Step into another maven project with IntelliJ

Tags: maven, debugging, intellij-idea

I have two maven projects: A and B. 
A is deployed to an internal maven repository

B's pom has A as a dependency.

For debugging purpose, I would like to start running B from IntelliJ and put a break on project A's source also in IntelliJ.  What are the minimal project changes needed for B for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: Debug 2 modules in same IntelliJ IDEA (Make reference between module A & module B).

Solution 2:
Use **[remote debug technique](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-remote.html)** for project A. (FYI: [link 1](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206840715-Debugging-problems-with-multi-module-projects-maven-dependencies?sort_by=votes), [link 2](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206259739-Remote-debugging-and-Maven-dependencies#))